# How to compare two CSV files and get the difference?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV files,

a1.csv

```
city,state,link
Aguila,Arizona,https://www.glendaleaz.com/planning/documents/AppendixAZONING.pdf
AkChin,Arizona,http://www.maricopa-az.gov/zoningcode/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Zoning-Code-Rewrite-Public-Review-Draft-3-Tracked-Edits-lowres1.pdf
Aguila,Arizona,http://www.co.apache.az.us/planning-and-zoning-division/zoning-ordinances/
```

a2.csv

```
city,state,link
Aguila,Arizona,http://www.co.apache.az.us
```

I want to get the difference.

Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('a1.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('a2.csv')

mask = a.isin(b.to_dict(orient='list'))
# Reverse the mask and remove null rows.
# Upside is that index of original rows that
# are now gone are preserved (see result).
c = a[~mask].dropna()
print c
```

**Expected Output:**

```
city,state,link
Aguila,Arizona,https://www.glendaleaz.com/planning/documents/AppendixAZONING.pdf
AkChin,Arizona,http://www.maricopa-az.gov/zoningcode/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Zoning-Code-Rewrite-Public-Review-Draft-3-Tracked-Edits-lowres1.pdf
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [city, state, link]
Index: []**
```

I want to check based on the first two rows, then if they are the same, remove it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, concatenate the DataFrames, then drop the duplicates while still keeping the first one. Then reset the index to keep it consistent.

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('a1.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('a2.csv')
c = pd.concat([a,b], axis=0)

c.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True) # Set keep to False if you don't want any
                                              # of the duplicates at all
c.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pandas` to read in two files, join them and remove all duplicate rows:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('a1.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('a2.csv')
ab = pd.concat([a,b], axis=0)
ab.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html