# How to compare content of two CSV files in pandas and find differences?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSV files. One contains a full list of names and the other one contains some of the names, each in one column called 'Name'.

Something like:

a.csv

```
Name
John
Robert
Ben
Frank
Felix
```

b.csv

```
Name
John
Robert
Ben
Frank
```

Note that Felix is missing in the second list.

I would like to read these two CSV files and determine the difference, i.e. Frank is missing in the second list. I came across the example below, which kind of does what I like, but struggle to apply it my example.

```
from collections import Counter
target_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
output_list = ['two','three','four', 'five']
Counter(target_list)-Counter(output_list)
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.  "i found some code" is nice, but still shows no analysis or coding effort.  You need to learn how to read your data from a file, store it into an applicable data structure, and apply the appropriate difference operation.  Each of these is a straightforward look-up, and certainly included in your educational materials.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This suggests a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The example you found does not use pandas. Do you have to use pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two CSV files and get the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693547/how-to-compare-two-csv-files-and-get-the-difference)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df1
     Name
0    John
1  Robert
2     Ben
3   Frank
4   Felix
>>> df2
     Name
0    John
1  Robert
2     Ben
3   Frank
>>> df1[~df1.Name.isin(df2.Name)]
    Name
4  Felix
```